# Bazel build from scratch error on resin/raspberry-pi3-debian

Tags: java, c++, raspberry-pi3, mmap, bazel

I got the following error attempting to build bazel from scratch ( https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html ) on resin/raspberry-pi3-debian Docker image.

This was very late in the compile process.

Thoughts?

`ERROR: /usr/local/src/bazel/third_party/ijar/BUILD:10:1: C++ compilation of rule '//third_party/ijar:zip' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command 
       (cd /tmp/bazel_aRLoR224/out/execroot/io_bazel && \
       exec env - \
        PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
         PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
       /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter     -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/third_party/ijar/_objs/zip/third_party/ijar/mapped_file_unix.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/third_party/ijar/_objs/zip/third_party/ijar/mapped_file_unix.o' -DBLAZE_OPENSOURCE -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/genfiles -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/arm-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem third_party/zlib -isystem bazel-out/arm-opt/genfiles/third_party/zlib -isystem bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/third_party/zlib -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c third_party/ijar/mapped_file_unix.cc -o bazel-out/arm-opt/bin/third_party/ijar/_objs/zip/third_party/ijar/mapped_file_unix.o)
     third_party/ijar/mapped_file_unix.cc: In constructor 'devtools_ijar::MappedOutputFile::MappedOutputFile(const char*, size_t)':
     third_party/ijar/mapped_file_unix.cc:114:67: error: no matching function for call to 'min(long unsigned int, unsigned int)'
                  std::numeric_limits::max());
                                    ^`